# How to display matrices and numbers on a single line in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a calculator for matrices using Tkinter and I want to display matrices and numbers on the same line like this:

```
1 2 3       1 2 3
4 5 6   +   4 5 6   +   2
7 8 9       6 7 8
```

Here is my code for representing a string version of a matrix:

```
 def __str__(self):
        '''
        (Matrix) -> String

        Returns the string representation of a matrix.
        '''
        s = ''
        for row in self.rows:
            for item in row:
                s += str(item)+ '  '
            s+= '\n'
        return s[:-1]
```

Currently I am using the Label widget and simply adding text to a string which is being displayed in the label. Whenever the user creates a matrix the string representation of the matrix is adding onto the string. The problem is the '\n' characters since they start a new line an from there on all text is displayed on that new line. How do I do it so that everything is on one line like the example above?

Comment: You can't iterate the **whole** matrix, you have to iterate **1.** `123` **2.** `456`, **3.** `789` and allways from both matrices, operator and numbers. Read about [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator). Pick one from [`[python] generator`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D+generator+understand)

Comment: `'\n'` characters are how lines in a `Label`s are delimited. To do what you want would require processing multiple matrices and operators at the same time and building-up the output line-by-line. While that's certainly possible. I suggest that you instead create a `Frame` container and put multiple `Label`s inside it side-by-side,This will allow the processing to be done one item at a time which would be much easier — and use something like your Matrix `__str__()` method on each `Label`.